# Why my computer doesnt recognize this 8gb memory?

Tags: memory, ddr3

My original memory es the is the 4gb and the one I bought is the 8gb,
but when I tried to run my comp, it doesn't recognize the 8gb.
Please tell me why.

Mi motherboard is a FOXCONN H61MXE, processor x64 bits, Intel core i5-2320 3.00gh.
I have right now 6 gb ram divided into two slots one of 4gb and the otherone 2 gb. I wanted an upgrade so i bought the 8gb(the one at the bottom of the picture), but when i install it alone or with the 4gb one it seems that my computer doesnt recognize it. my motherboard supports 16gb ram

[image: area]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Foxconn H61MXE](http://foxconn.ru/products/mb/intel/150/) supports DDR3 1333/1066 unbuffered RAM.

The one you installed is 1600 Registered/Buffered.

Ergo, the memory is not supported by the motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a several reasons that you can troubleshoot:

1. Motherboard capacity: The bus speed of your 8GB RAM whether it is supported the mother board. Check the supported capacity as well.
2. Compatibility: Not all motherboards go well with all RAMs available in the market.
3. Assembly: Was it mounted well? Was there a click?
4. Contact Point: Are you're slotting the new RAM into an unused slot?
5. Voltage: Some RAMs have low voltage, some normal.